# running module within a package getting no module error

Tags: python

I want to organize my python project like so:

```
/proj
   /test
      __init__.py
      test.py
   /utils
      __init__.py
      util.py
```

Inside `test.py` I have want to import a class from `utils.util`

`from utils.util import classA`

However, I get an error when I run `test.py` when I am in the `/proj` directory:

```
$ python test/test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from utils.util import classA
ImportError: No module named utils.util
```

However, if I make these changes, the code runs fine (`python test.py`)

```
/proj
   test.py
   /utils
      __init__.py
      util.py
```

I would really like to be able to organize my code like I did at the first example without getting errors. How can I enable myself to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run it as a package.

```
python -m test.test
```

Answer (score 2):

**How importing works**

When you try to import a module, Python searches through directories in PYTHONPATH, looking for the module you are importing.

So, when you write `from utils.util import classA`, it looks for directory named `utils`, which contains file `util.py` (and `__init__.py`, but that is a different issue). Directory `utils` must be on your PYTHONPATH.

**What happens in your case**

You can see what is on your path if you put this in the script:

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

When you print that, you will probably see it contins an empty string `''`. That means the directory where your script (`test.py`) is. So, if `utils` direcory is in the same place where `test.py` is, Python will be able to find it. Otherwise it won't.

**How to fix it**

Make sure `utils` is on the path. There are different ways to do that, e.g.

- put your entry script in the root (as in your example which works); or
- add the root directory to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable before running `python test.py`
- add the root directory to the `sys.path` from within `test.py` before importing anything

Edit: or, as Sayan wrote:

- run it as `python -m test.test` (do that from the root directory)

Answer (score 0):

You can do module relative imports. Try:

```
from ..utils.util import classA
```

in your `test.py`